# Deployment of .Net web Application on Linux

Tags: asp.net, linux, apache, deployment, web-applications

What are the steps for deploying the .Net Web Application on Linux & apache web server developed using .NET Framework using Visual Studio 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure you compiled/developed for .NET 2.0 (otherwise mono might complain)
- Install mod_mono
- Put the files on the linux server, they should run immedatly
- See how slow it runs and buy a windows server

IMHO .NET Applications on Linux still have a long way to go until they are really useable.